# How to I write a .sh file to activate my program?

Tags: command-line, scripts, 18.04

I have project in home/myname/projectFoleder/ and I wrote a script to run aqueduct server as shown below. When I click my .sh file it runs the script and starts the server.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Startup Capital Script.
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
#

set -v 
aqueduct serve
exec $SHELL
```

I need to create a another .sh file in desktop so user can click and activate the server. I try to write a script to use cd to point the home/myname/projectFoleder/ and use ./myfirst.sh to activate the server and nothings happen. By the way I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

Any help please?

Comment: I may be off-base (somewhat confused), but my thoughts are:  Is it the same user? or a different user, as a different user won't have permissions to your user directory unless you've allowed it (`chmod`).  Did you give the script execute permissions (for all, or just you?).  I'd also suggest adding a shebang (#!/bin/bash as first line, or whatever shell you prefer) as the first line.

Comment: In DMZ we have ubuntu desktop 18.04. There is one user at the moment. Whoever responsible will use same user to login and just clicks the .sh on desktop to activate the aqueduct serve. Yes, I have a #!/bin/bash in first line.

Comment: @NTMS i'm probably saying totally irresponsible, have you try to add a little `sudo` at your "shortcut" script?

Comment: @NTMS please also add your second script to your question. Do you see an error message when running the second script from a terminal?